# How can I find echo dot's MAC address without turning it off?

Tags: alexa, amazon-echo

My home network has a MAC filter, so I need to know the MAC address of this particular echo dot. I have nearly 30 smart devices connected to my router and I do not have the luxury of turning off one by one and to check. Also I can not turn off this echo dot.

I tried with this Android app call 'fing', but couldn't find. But I found a device with MAC vendor call 'Espressif'.

Asking Alexa 'what is your MAC address' did not work.

Is there a way that I can find MAC address or at least MAC vendor of echo dot?

Comment: Read this: https://www.amazon.com/forum/amazon%20discussions%20feedback?_encoding=UTF8&cdForum=FxLCMW9UN2N6QR&cdThread=Tx1D17KFSXISFHK and find out why not to use MAC filtering at all.

Comment: So you have a mac filter but no logs of unknown device to alert you if something try to hijack your network ? That's either unclear or a bad setup

Comment: @mico, that comment stream on the Amazon forum was painful to read. It was like listening to annoying little kids arguing  "does not!", "does too!"  And it never did arrive at a conclusive statement.  All that said, you are correct that MAC filtering is of little-positive-to-some-negative value, and not using a MAC filter generally solves more problems than it creates.

Answer (score 9):

1. MAC vendor info is actually part of MAC address (check out on [wikipedia_link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address))
2. If you have any laptop/PC/Mac attached to the network try to discover it by typing simple command in command prompt/shell 
   [ arp -a ]
3. You can use [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) network sniffer.
4. There is list of sniffers on [Insecure.Org](http://insecure.org) web. One of tools 
   which can be used is [nmap]

   [nmap -sP 172.16.30.0/24]

This will give you detailed MAC report, for example:

```
MAC Address: 00:15:99:95:16:EE (Samsung Electronics Co.)
Nmap scan report for host1.x.com (172.16.30.x)

MAC Address: E4:1F:13:3F:99:24 (IBM)
Nmap scan report for host2.x.com (172.16.30.y)

MAC Address: 50:E5:49:81:45:DA (Giga-byte Technology Co.)
Nmap scan report for 172.16.30.z
```

Comment: `arp -a` will only show you what that machine has recently heard, ie, only if the device has been sending active broadcast traffic or if you recently pinged it.  Still, if you do some activity with the dot, it might then work.

Comment: Please check wireshark network sniffer. You have link inside answer body.

Comment: Again, either one will only be able to see it if it is sending broadcast traffic.  Promiscuous mode sniffing doesn't get much on wifi, unless you do it on the access point.  But it may not be that hard to get an echo device to generate broadcast traffic just by interacting with it normally or initially turning it on.  Worst case  "Alexa, discover devices" should send some local broadcast traffic.

Answer (score 9):

Since you asked Alexa for its MAC address, I would assume it is or has been connected to the internet.

Log in to your account at alexa.amazon.com, go to "Settings" > [your Dot] under "Devices", and at the bottom under "About" you will find the MAC address of your device.

Answer (score 3):

You can open up a browser, go to Alexa.Amazon.com and login to your Echo.

Then go to Settings and Select your device.

Scroll all the way down to About:

[image]